# Passing optional parameters via http call in angular

Tags: angular

I have written a service method in Angular 8 which has optional parameter. I am getting a compile time error saying no overload matches this call. The error is at return statement. Could somebody tell me what the issue is ?

Service method

```
public getOutstandingAgreements(userAgreementId?: number): Observable<AgreementsModel[]> {
    console.log('getOutstandingAgreements is getting called');
    let params = {argument1: userAgreementId};
    if (userAgreementId) {
        params = {argument1: userAgreementId};
    }
    return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params: params});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public getOutstandingAgreements(userAgreementId?: number):Observable<AgreementsModel[]> {
    console.log('getOutstandingAgreements is getting called');
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (userAgreementId) {
        params = params.set("argument1", userAgreementId.toString())
    }
    return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params});
  }
```